# Reading the results of a Casbah MongoDB query

Tags: scala, mongodb, casbah

I have a document in MongoDB that looks like this:

```
{"_id":"asdf", "data":[
    {"a":"1","b":"2"}, 
    {"a":"3","b":"4"}, 
    {"a":"5","b":"6"}, 
]}
```

I would like to query that object using Scala, and convert the entries in "data" into a list of case classes. <strike>After a few hours' work, I've yet to come up with something that even compiles. Can someone point me to a tutorial with this information? [This tutorial](http://api.mongodb.org/scala/casbah/current/tutorial.html) hasn't been any help. I've tried every combination of nested maps, fors, foreaches, casts, and pattern matching that I can come up with.</strike>

Edit: My super-ugly but now seemingly working code is now this:

```
def getData(source_id:String) = {
    val source = collection.findOne(MongoDBObject("_id" -> source_id)).get
    val data = source.get("data").asInstanceOf[BasicDBList]

    var ret:List[Data] = List()

    val it = presses.iterator
    while(it.hasNext) {
        val item = it.next.asInstanceOf[BasicDBObject]

        ret = Data(
            item.get("a").asInstanceOf[String],
            item.get("b").asInstanceOf[String]
        ) :: ret
    }

    ret
}
```

Please, someone tell me there's a better way.

Answer (score 1):

As you are using case classes anyway, the easiest solution is to just use [salat](https://github.com/novus/salat) – it will automatically serialize/deserialize to and from a mongo connection with very little boilerplate.

A minor point, but in your code you should be able to simply `map` across the DBObject holding structure rather than manually mutate the `ret` variable:

```
val ret = presses.map { item => Data(…) }
```

you may need to call .toList if you really want a List (though you may only need Seq or Iterable)

Comment: There's no map method on BasicDBList. Also no toList method, which someone suggested elsewhere. Am I working with the wrong library or something?

Comment: I was looking at the MongoDBObject class, not the java driver classes. Looking closer you'd actually want mapResult which you pass a function that takes a Map. You're probably better off using MongoDBObject as the source – that at least has getAs[T] so you don't need to manually cast.

MongoDBList is the class that defines toList (and toSeq, toStream etc.)

Comment: Yes, I'd love to use MongoDBObject, but unfortunately findOne().get seems to return a BasicDBObject, which can't be cast to MongoDBObject.